# why my program does not work in second for loop?

Tags: python

I want to loop over 20 inputs and calculate the divisors of them and then show the most number of  divisors. In my second for loop I have an error
that says: the `e` is not defined. Can someone explain the issue?

another question:
how can I show the input that has the most number of divisors?

```
for i in range (20) :
    x=int(input())
    list1=[]
    list2=[]
    count=0
    for e in range ( e,x+1):
        if x%e==0 :
        count=count+1  
list1.append(count)
list2.append(x)
print(max(count))
```

Comment: the 'e' is not defined that is the problem

Comment: You have used 'e' in "..range( e,.. " without initializing it.

Comment: value of e should be 1

Answer (score 1):

## for maximum number of divisor

```
list1=[]
list2=[]

for i in range (20) :
    x=int(input())
    count=0
    for e in range ( 1,x+1):
        if x%e==0 :
            count=count+1  
    list1.append(count)
    list2.append(x)
print(max(list1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Within your code, you have reference to the variable `e` in your second range function.

```
for e in range ( e,x+1):
```

At this point of execution in the code, `e` will not be defined. In your instance, you need to set this to be 1. As you want from 1 -> x+1.

```
for e in range (1,x+1):
```

To get the most common occurance you can make use of the standard library collections module.

`import collections`

Something like:

```
import collections
list1=[]
list2=[]
for i in range (20) :
    x=int(input())
    count=0
    for e in range (1,x+1):
        if x%e==0 :
            count=count+1  
    list1.append(count)
    list2.append(x)
    # print(max(count))

c = collections.Counter(list)
k, v = c.most_common(1)[0] # need to get 0 index as its a list
print(k, v) # prints the key and the number of occurances.
```

Comment: @iman-j if this answer resolves your question please think about accepting this answer (✓).

Answer (score 1):

Initialize `e` with an int value before starting the for loop

```
e = 1   # for example
for e in range ( e,x+1):
```

As for getting the most divisors and the number with the most divisor you can print that along with it. You need to format your code and indentations properly. Currently, your `list.append` code only runs once. Not for each loop.

I have re-written your code to work as expected.

It will print both the number with the most divisors and the number of divisors.

```
maxDivisorNumber = None
maxDivisorCount = 0
for i in range (20) :
    x=int(input())
    count=0
    e = 1
    for e in range ( e,x+1):
        if x%e==0:
            count+=1  
    if count>maxDivisorCount:
        maxDivisorCount, maxDivisorNumber = count, x

print(maxDivisorCount, maxDivisorNumber)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in range (20) :
x=int(input())
list1=[]
list2=[]
count=0
j = 1 # Setting a new var. Because your provided 'e' is not assigned anywhere
for e in range ( j,x+1):
    if x%e==0 :
    count=count+1
```

list1.append(count)
list2.append(x)
print(max(count))